# Adding HTML elements dynamically in nested sections

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add a bunch of HTML elements to my page dynamically.

I have following sections of elements in the page :

```
  `Company section :` has EIN, Company Name and Delete controls.
  `Control Group section :` Control Group name, Delete group link, one or more company sections, and a Add button.
```

functioning of buttons on the page :

1. `Add Control Group`: Clicking on this button should add a new control group section as shown in the below image.

   [image]
2. `Delete Group` : Clicking on this should delete the corresponding Control group section.

3.
    `Add` : should add the elements related to the company section in the corresponding Control Group.  Company section as shown in the below image.

[image]

4. `Delete` : should delete the elements related to the company section in the corresponding Control Group.

   I put the code in  [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ynHNmMhn3YGU4MxXqDR0?p=preview)

   I am getting lost in adding and delteing the Company section in each Control Group. Also the code is failing to add more than one Control Group sections.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how you want your UI to work but the obvious problem I see is that you're using splice incorrectly.

I assume you only want to remove a single element from the array when the user clicks delete.  If so, change your `splice` command to this:  `splice(index, 1)`.

I've also changed how you access the specific element to remove from the array by using Angular's `$index` inside the `ng-repeat`. For example, I've changed the `removeControlGroup()` function to this:

```
$scope.removeControlGroup = function (index) {
     $scope.ClientGroupsInfo.splice(index, 1);
};
```

In your HTML, you need to pass the index of the array to splice like this:

```
<a ng-click="removeControlGroup($index)"> Delete Group </a>
```

In the HTML, `$index` will be a numerical value from 0 to the length of your array (minus 1) and will tell the `removeControlGroup` function which index of the array needs to be removed.  Previously, the delete button would delete the last item in the array.

[Updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/J3fXqQsDuUyXsOGZfyg0?p=preview)

Comment: Hi, I updated the question with images.   Clicking on the Add Control Group each time should  add a new section as shown in the first image in the question.  Clicking on the corresponding delte should delete that section. Similarily clicking on Add button should add the Company section as shown in the second image in the question.

Comment: The updated plunker is not adding a new Control Group section on each click of 'Add Control Group'